# Django templates how to use tags and template filters to get data from json dict

Tags: json, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm having dict which can be seen here https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a570322381fc45919a7a03ebad78cbee

but from what I was reading so far, it's more likely a list of dicts. I am trying to display data from dicts like title, description, authors and categories but template tags are not displaying this what I want, tried with loops but can't access it

Tried loops like this

```
{% for items in books %}
    {% for volumeInfo in items %}
        {{ volumeInfo.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

only what works is {{ books.items }} but it's giving me the whole json but I need only few values.

```py
def api(request):
    books = {}
    if 'books' in request.GET:
        books = request.GET['books']
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%s' % books
        response = requests.get(url)
        books = response.json()
        print(type(books))
        with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
            json.dump(books, write_file)

    return render(request, 'books/api.html', {'books': books})
```

```
{% load get_item from template_filters %}
{% block content %}
  <h2>Google API</h2>
  <form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="book">
    <button type="submit">search on google books api</button>
  </form>
  {% if books %}
    <p>
{% for items in books %}
{% for volumeInfo in items %}
{{ volumeInfo.title }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{{ books.items }}
    </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the structure of the JSON that you have. Summarising, the data looks like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "Hobbit czyli Tam i z powrotem"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, in the template:

```
{% for item in books.items %}
  {{ item.volumeInfo.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel for claryfing and help :)